# Is the mapping [a,b] to R3 always bounded?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I was wondering whether the mapping [a,b] to R3 is always bounded even if the mapping is not continuous. If the mapping is continuous I think we can easily show the image (which would be a curve) is bounded. Since [a,b] is a compact set in R and the mapping is continuous, that implies each of the component function $(f_1,f_2,f_3)$ are continuous and since compactness is preserved, the mapping $f_n$ : [a,b] to R is compact so it is bounded, which implies the curve is bounded.

Now what happen if the component functions are not continuous? We probably don't have a curve. It could be some crazy disconnected shape, but I think the image is still bounded. The reason is because we have the closed interval [a,b] and not (a,b). So even if one of the component function is something like 1/z, the fact that [a,b] is compact implies that none of the component shoots off to infinity. Is this true?

Comment: consider $\begin{cases} 1/x & x\neq 0 \\ \text{anything} &x=0\end{cases}$

Comment: You can even have  a map with range $\mathbb R^{3}$ (by a cardinality argument).

Comment: If you don't assume continuity or any other assumption for a function, the function can be very weird.  The geometry becomes rather irrelevant because you haven't put any geometric restrictions.

Comment: I take it we're assuming $a\ne b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not true. To provide a direct counterexample, it might be easier to see @CalvinKhor's example in 3 dimensions. Say $[a, b] = [0, 1]$, and say $$ f(x) = \begin{cases} \langle\frac{1}{x},\frac{1}{x}, \frac{1}{x}\rangle & x \neq 0 \\ \langle 0, 0, 0\rangle & x = 0  \end{cases}$$ Then $f$ is such a map, but it is not bounded.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Also do you know if space filling curves, say those that map [a,b] to the unit cube are continuous and smooth? I feel like those are pathological curves that you would want to rule out.

Comment: I think they can be continuous (the Hilbert curve is, I believe), but the certainly aren't smooth. In fact, they can't be differentiable: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/201424/proof-that-no-differentiable-space-filling-curve-exists